# Job hunting while ongoing first project

Tags: recruitment, switzerland

So, I have been working at a company for 13 months and I really want to finish the project I'm working on. It's really just a good way to increase my experience and to prove my competences. And I'm not very happy with the money I earn, and I'd like to start job hunting to increase my compensation.

The project won't be finished for about another 11 months. And I'd like to have it go live and solve problems with it, as well as have a backtrace of sending something live and being able to prove it.

I'm in Switzerland where resignation time is 3 month.

So what can I do ?

- Start job hunting, saying I'm only available in 11 months. Won't a job recruiter be reluctant to hire a guy that isn't available ? Can I tell them I'm only available in 8 months, isn't that a red flag?
- Wait 8 month, and start job hunting when I can hand a resignation notice if someone wants to hire me?
- This is all pointless and I should job hunt asap and leave as soon as possible? I'll get that experience at the next job anyway.

Also, how do I put that project in my resume, knowing it's not finished?

PS : to add some context, this is my first job in the field, and I'm self taught. I'd have been very happy to get this job, but friends who are also self taught pointed out to me that with the same time working they get way more. But I've been in this longer than expected project.

Comment: Be sure that you actually can disclose or include such project in your CV... sometimes contracts come with NDAs that would prevent you from mentioning the project you did... regardless, the technology stack that such project uses is something that can be included (in other words, perhaps you won't be able to give many details of the project and why it's great, but you can tell that you have experience in techs A, B, and C that you used in projects).

Answer (score 3):

> Start job hunting, saying I'm only availible in 11 month. Won't job recruiter be reluctant to hire a guy taht isn't availible ? Can I tell them I'm only availible in 8 month, isn't that a redflag ?

That's unlikely to work. It would be very rare to find a hiring manager that would be willing to wait this long.

> Wait 8 month, and start job hunting when I can hand a resignation notice if someone want to hire me ?

That's certainly an option. You can actually start 1 or 2 month earlier. It typically takes a while for an actual offer to materialize. If you are fortunate to get an offer "too early" you can negotiate a bit of a delay. If your customary notice period is 3 month asking for an extra few weeks is not unreasonable.

> This is all pointless and I should job junt asap and leave as soon as possible ? I'll get that experience at the next job anyway.

That's perfectly fine too. This is a personal decision about how you weigh the two options.

One thing to consider: You probably want to make sure that your next job is viable for at least 3 years or so. Staying for two years and successfully finishing a project certainly looks better on the resume so it might enable you do land a better 2nd job.

There is nothing wrong with trying both: Start looking now and if your perfect job happens to comes along: go for it. If the opportunities are less interesting, take a break, focus on excelling at your project and resume the search in 8 or 9 months when you are on the finish line.

Comment: If it's the first job I wouldn't freak out too much about staying, just because 2 years looks better on the CV than 1. As long as you have a good explanation why that job didn't fit, didn't let you grow or whatever, it's not that big of a deal in my experience.